# How to use MyEtherWallet API to generate ETH Wallet Address upon signup in Laravel

Tags: myetherwallet

We have a Laravel project that is currently developed now. However, we would want to create an Ethereum Wallet Address upon signup but we don't know what to do with it. We have downloaded a GitHub repo for MyEtherWallet but we don't know how to use it with Laravel. Is there's someone who can help us out? Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't know much about Laravel except that it is a PHP framework. Have a look at https://readthedocs.org/projects/web3php/ (web3 PHP). You should be able to create account addresses through the apis here

Comment: @MarkJerlyBundalian so that API work for you to create wallet pub and private key?